# Why doesn't gcc use memmove in std::uninitialized_copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl

[`std::uninitialized_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) copies into an uninitialized range of memory. 
This could be done using `memmove` for bitwise copyable types.
I stepped through below example code in gdb (compiling with gcc 5.2.0).
Thereby I observed that `memmove` isn't used at all.

In the example `__is_trivial(Bar)` is used to determine whether `memmove` may be used. 
It (correctly) evaluates to `false` as `Bar` has a non-trivial default constructor (cf. call to `std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy(...)` in `bits/stl_uninitialized.h` line `123`ff). 
But why is `__is_trivial` even relevant to `std::uninitialized_copy`? 
According to [Bjarne](https://books.google.de/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1020&dq=uninitialized_copy+stroustrup+optimization&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAGoVChMIo4nyhpHyyAIVw80UCh3rPAJ_#v=onepage&q=uninitialized_copy%20stroustrup%20optimization&f=false) [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) should be sufficient. Note that the latter evaluates to `true` in the example, ie. the `memmove` optimization [is applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16542385/2747160).

I'm aware, that the standard does not require any specific implementation of `std::uninitialized_copy`. I'm just wondering why `__is_trivial` is favored even if `std::is_trivially_copyable` is present as an applicable alternative to the gcc implementation?

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

struct Bar
{
   Bar () : v(42) {};
   Bar(Bar const &) = default;
   Bar(Bar &&) = default;
   Bar & operator=(Bar &&) = default;
   Bar & operator=(Bar const &) = default;
   ~Bar() = default;
   int v;
};

int main() {
   std::cout
      << std::is_trivially_move_constructible<Bar>::value
      << " " << std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<Bar>::value
      << " " << std::is_trivially_copyable<Bar>::value
      << " " << std::is_trivial<Bar>::value
      << " " << __is_trivial(Bar) << std::endl;
   size_t const num_elements = 1 << 27;
   std::vector<Bar> v(num_elements);
   Bar * vc = (Bar *) std::malloc(num_elements * sizeof(Bar));
   std::uninitialized_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), vc);
   std::free(vc);
}
```

Example Output: `1 1 1 0 0`

**Update**: We did some tests comparing actual runtimes of `memmove`, `uninitialized_copy` and a simple `for` loop. If `Bar` is trivial (cf. `__is_trivial(Bar)`), `uninitialized_copy` is as fast as `memmove`, if it's not, `uninitialized_copy` is as fast as our `for` loop. Overall `memmove` was only significantly faster (`2x`) on small `Bar`s (ie. change `int v;` to `char v;`). Otherwise the performance was essentially the same.

**Edit**: Correct references to `std::is_trivially_...`. State title more precisely.

Comment: You are mixing up `is_trivially_copy_constructible` and `is_trivially_copyable`. Bjarne's example code uses the second, not the first.

Comment: That's true, I've corrected the question. The problem remains though as `is_trivially_copyable` evaluates to `true` as well.

Comment: You copy to an uninitialized range of memory. The way I interpret it, there cannot be overlaps (since one is initialized the other is not), so you could use `memcpy` instead of `memmove`.

Comment: libstdc++ welcomes patches (or bugzilla entries if you don't want to spend the time).

Comment: Note that GCC doesn't have a `__is_trivially_copyable` intrinsic until GCC 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers: This has been submitted as a gcc enhancement [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68350).