# uninitialized_copy memcpy/memmove optimization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I've recently started to examine the STL in the MSVC's implementation. There are some nice tricks there, however I don't know why the following criteria is used.

The `std::uninitialized_copy` is optimized to a simple `memcpy/memmove` if some conditions are met. As my understanding the input range can be `memcpy`'d to the uninitialized area if the target type U `is_trivially_copy_constructible` from source type T.

However the MSVC implementation checks a hell lot of thing before choosing the `memcpy` instead of the one-by-one copy-constructing of elements. I did not want to paste the related code here, instead I'm sharing it through pastebin if anyone is interested: https://pastebin.com/Sa4Q7Qj0

The base algorithm for the `uninitialized_copy` is something like this (exception-handling is omitted for readibility)

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline void construct_in_place(T& obj, Args&&... args)
{
    ::new (static_cast<void*>(addressof(obj)) T(forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename In, typename Out>
inline Out uninitialized_copy(In first, In last, Out dest)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first, ++dest)
        construct_in_place(*dest, *first);
}
```

This can be optimized to a `memcpy/memmove` if the copy-constructing doesn't do any 'special' thing (trivially copy-constructible).

The MS's implementation requires the following:

- T trivially assignable to U
- T trivially copyable to U
- T being trivial
- extra checks (like sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)) if T != U

So for example the following struct cannot be `memcpy`'d:

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    Foo() : i(10) { }
};
```

but the following is ok:

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    Foo() = default; // or simply omit
};
```

Shouldn't it be enough to check if type U can be trivially copy-constructed from type T? Because all that's the uninitialized_copy does.

For example, I can't see why the following is not memcpy'd by the MS's STL implementation (NOTE: I know the reason, it is the user-defined constructor, but I don't understand the logic behind it):

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;

    Foo() noexcept
        : i(10)
    {
    }

    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
};

void test()
{
    // please forgive me...
    uint8 raw[256];
    Foo* dest = (Foo*)raw;
    Foo src[] = { Foo(), Foo() };

    bool b = std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<Foo>::value;  // true
    bool b2 = std::is_trivially_copyable<Foo>::value;           // true

    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(src)); // seems ok

    // uninitialized_copy does not use memcpy/memmove, it calls the copy-ctor one-by-one
    std::uninitialized_copy(src, src + sizeof(src) / sizeof(src[0]), dest);
}
```

Related SO post: [Why doesn't gcc use memmove in std::uninitialized_copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482610/why-doesnt-gcc-use-memmove-in-stduninitialized-copy)

### Update

As @Igor Tandetnik pointed out in the comments, it is not safe to say if there is no user-defined copy constructor then the type T is trivially copy-constructible. He provided the following example:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string data;
};
```

In this example, there is no user-defined copy constructor and it is still not trivially copy-constructible. Thank you for the correction, I modified the original post based on the feedback.

Comment: "No user-defined constructor" != "trivially constructible". `struct S { std::string str; };` doesn't have user-defined constructors, but it is not trivially constructible; `memcpy` certainly won't copy it properly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, that's true. Let's forget what I said, and stick with the "trivially constructible" form. :) It's enough to test wheter the type T is trivially copy constructible, isn't it?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but your `raw` buffer needs to use `alignof(Foo)` to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uninitialized_copy` has two responsibilities: First, it has to make sure that the right bit-pattern gets into the destination buffer. Second, it has to *start the lifetime* of the C++ objects in that buffer. That is, it must call a constructor of some kind, unless the C++ Standard specifically grants it permission to skip that constructor call.

According to my very incomplete research, it appears that right now only [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) types are guaranteed to have their bit patterns preserved by `memcpy`/`memmove`; memcpying any other kind of type (even if it happens to be trivially copy-constructible and/or trivially copy-assignable!) formally produces undefined behavior.

And furthermore, it appears that right now only [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) types can "pop into existence" without a constructor call. ([P0593 "Implicit creation of objects..."](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r5.html) proposes a lot of changes in this area, maybe in C++2b.)

Jonathan Wakely's comment on [libstdc++ bug 68350](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68350) seems to indicate that GNU libstdc++ is trying to remain within the letter of the law by never "popping into existence" any objects of non-trivial type — even though, as a C++ implementation, they do have latitude to exploit platform-specific behavior in the name of performance. I would guess that MSVC is following similar logic, for similar reasons (whatever those reasons are).

---

You can see the vendors' unwillingness to "pop objects into existence" by comparing their willingness to optimize `std::copy` versus `std::uninitialized_copy` on class types which are "trivially copyable but not trivial." Being trivially copyable means `std::copy` can use `memcpy` to assign-over-existing-objects; but `std::uninitialized_copy`, to make those objects pop into existence in the first place, still feels the need to call *some* constructor in a loop — even if it's the trivial copy constructor!

```
class C { int i; public: C() = default; };
class D { int i; public: D() {} };
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<C> && !std::is_aggregate_v<C>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<D> && !std::is_aggregate_v<D>);

void copyCs(C *p, C *q, int n) {
    std::copy(p, p+n, q);  // GNU and MSVC both optimize
    std::uninitialized_copy(p, p+n, q);  // GNU and MSVC both optimize
}
void copyDs(D *p, D *q, int n) {
    std::copy(p, p+n, q);  // GNU and MSVC both optimize
    std::uninitialized_copy(p, p+n, q);  // neither GNU nor MSVC optimizes :(
}
```

---

You wrote:

> Shouldn't it be enough to check if type U can be trivially copy-constructed from type T? Because that's all uninitialized_copy does.

Yes, but when T and U are **different**, you're not doing "trivial copy-construction"; you're doing a "trivial construction" that is *not* copy-construction. And unfortunately the C++ Standard defines `is_trivially_constructible<T,U>` to mean something different from what humans mean by "trivial"! My blog post ["Trivially-constructible-from" (July 2018)](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/03/trivially-constructible-from/) gives this example:

```
assert(is_trivially_constructible_v<u64, u64b>);
// Yay!

using u16 = short;
assert(is_trivially_constructible_v<u64, u16>);
// What the...

assert(is_trivially_constructible_v<u64, double>);
// ...oh geez.
```

This explains some of MSVC's

> extra checks (like sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)) if T != U

Specifically, MSVC's [`_Ptr_cat_helper<T*,U*>::_Really_trivial`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/4aaa0135d965e41690bbd555c71d74e34d459c26/stl/inc/xutility#L1382-L1417) trait relies on those extra checks to detect some (but not all) common situations where the conversion from T to U is "really" trivial in the human/bitwise sense, and not just trivial in the C++-Standard sense. This allows MSVC to optimize copying an array of `int*` into an array of `const int*`, which is something libstdc++ can't do:

```
using A = int*;
using B = const int*;

void copyAs(A *p, B *q, int n) {
    std::uninitialized_copy(p, p+n, q);  // only MSVC optimizes
}
void copyBs(B *p, B *q, int n) {
    std::uninitialized_copy(p, p+n, q);  // GNU and MSVC both optimize
}
```